# How can develop module in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I have started Sitecore learning few months ago.That time first question come in my mind is that how can I develop module? but can not able to find documentation. Can anybody provide me documentation how can I develop custom module?

Comment: Nothing special about a module you call your code a module and it is and module. do you have more specific question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you would like to create a module for the [Sitecore marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net), as others have done, then the process is fairly simple.

1. Write your code (ASCX, ASPX, CS, JS, etc.)
2. Create your Sitecore items (Layouts, renderings/sublayouts, custom buttons, etc.)
3. Create your configuration files (if necessary) for the App_Config\Include folder.
4. Build your solution and test it in a Sitecore instance locally.
5. Package the published files and item together using the Sitecore packaging utility.
6. Contribute your module on the marketplace and upload the package for review.

What you are hoping to achieve here is that another person could grab your package, install it on their system, and be able to use it without needing to recompile your source code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop a module, come up with the idea and then build it.

You can then submit it to the Sitecore a Marketplace under the contribute section.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Contribute.aspx?sc_lang=en

Typically you'll submit a package to this section and documentation on how to setup and use the module.

Sitecore will then test the module and inform you whether it is suitable for the marketplace. Your module will then be published on the marketplace ready for others to download.

When developing your module you should consider compatibility with Sitecore versions, and you should also test it thoroughly.

Here's some more info on best practices when building modules:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/831724